# Remove .php extension and replace / with question mark

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to take the URL below

`http://localhost/gbm/file/services`

And send it to

`http://localhost/gbm/file.php?param=services`

With the code in .htaccess I have now, It is just removing the `.php` extension but not replacing `/` and adding the other string to `id=`

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /gbm/

## don't touch /forum URIs
RewriteRule ^forums/ - [L,NC]

## hide .php extension snippet

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]

# To remove www header
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^gbm/(\w+)/(.*) /gbm/$1.php/?param=$2
```

Comment: Try replacing [L] (last) flag with [QSA] (query string append) like this: `RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [QSA]` - [L] flag tells the server to stop processing rules, so it does not reach the last rule, which is supposed to append `param` to query string

Comment: But still, it is not appending the param to the query string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /gbm/

## don't touch /forum URIs
RewriteRule ^forums/ - [L,NC]

# To remove www header
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(\w+)\.php\?param=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [R=301,L,NE]

## hide .php extension snippet

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,NE,L]

# handle ?param=...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/gbm/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/([\w-]+)/?$ $1.php?param=$2 [L,QSA]


# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Using these rules in my .htaccess when I enter `http://localhost/file.php?param=services` in browser it gets redirected to `http://localhost/gbm/file/services`

Comment: Try doing vice versa. I need to take `http://localhost/gbm/file/services` to `http://localhost/file.php?param=services` internally

Comment: Yes of course `http://localhost/gbm/file/services` woks as well by rewriting to   `http://localhost/gbm/file.php?param=services` internally.

Comment: It is working! Thank You!! And does the same rules apply for files in the folders in gbm directory? because, it is showing 500 internal server error

Comment: With these rules I am not getting any 500 for request e.g. `http://localhost/gbm/contact` where `contact.php` is a valid file in `gbm` directory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118974/discussion-between-vyshnavi-samudrala-and-anubhava).